# Jump to HTML anchor on another page without having #name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website and want to link it to a particular anchor on another page.

The original way of doing this would be to
    `<a href="/page#contact">Contact</a>`
The new page would then be 
    `http://website.com/page#contact`

Is there a way to still link it to the anchor without having the url display as
`http://website.com/page#contact`?

Thank You

Comment: Why? Why do this? Rather than let the user see the URL complete with the fragment identifier?

Answer (score 1):

No. To do that, you'd have to be able to link to a page and force it to scroll *without* using a fragment ("#contact"), and there's no standard or common way to do that without code on the *target* page enabling it.

If you can write code for the target page, you could do this:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
  var hash = location.hash.replace(/^#$/, '');
  if (hash) {
    location.hash = "";
  };
}, 0);
</script>
```

But again, you have to be able to put code on the target page.